# System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Server RPC unavailable

Tags: c#, exception, printing

Sorry for duplicate, but I have another situation.
I have a little program which realize printPreview and print processes.

```
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString(
        "Hello World",
        new Font("Times New Roman", 16, FontStyle.Bold),
        Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count; i++)
    {
        str += PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters[i] + "\n";
    }

    MessageBox.Show(str);

    try
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        PrinterSettings prnSet = new PrinterSettings();

        if (PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Count > 0)
        {
            PageSettings ps = new PageSettings(prnSet);
            ps.Margins.Left = 10;
            ps.Margins.Right = 20; ps.Margins.Top = 10; ps.Margins.Bottom = 20;
            printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
        }            
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }            
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
    printDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

When I run it from VS everything works, but when I run it from release folder - I get this exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Server RPC is unavailable
    at System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.get_InstalledPrinters()
    at printStudy.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\printStudy\Form1.cs:line 37
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
    at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

I tried to restart printer spooling process but no result. (User has admin privileges).

P.S. I setup Debug->Exceptions check everything in thrown in VS for that VS shows me any exceptions during debugging, but VS started program without any problems. Why do problems appear when I run it from release/debug folder? And how to solve it?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/734628/what-causes-system-drawing-printing-printersettings-installedprinters-to-throw-w

Comment: I've already seen it. And it doesn't help me

Comment: Remove all installed printers.  Add them back one by one until you find the troublemaker.

Comment: yeah, the problem is on my drivers for printers. I could run program in virtual pc and it runs well. So, now I know what to do.